# Test coverage results dropped after upgrading to jest 26

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs, code-coverage

I recently pulled in the latest jest version to a node/typescript project and our previous 100% test coverage (woo) dropped way down.

jest 25 coverage results (after a small change):

```
Jest: "global" coverage threshold for statements (100%) not met: 99.83%
Jest: "global" coverage threshold for branches (100%) not met: 99.05%
Jest: "global" coverage threshold for lines (100%) not met: 99.81%
```

jest 26 coverage results:

```
Jest: "global" coverage threshold for statements (100%) not met: 84.21%
Jest: "global" coverage threshold for branches (100%) not met: 68.02%
Jest: "global" coverage threshold for lines (100%) not met: 94.25%
Jest: "global" coverage threshold for functions (100%) not met: 86.44%
```

I'd be very interested to hear from anyone who has some insight into the reason for the change. I didn't see anything that stands out in the [release notes](https://jestjs.io/blog/2020/05/05/jest-26)

Comment: Same problem here. We have a huge project with Nx and Angular on board. Around 100 libs, where coverages of 20 of them just dropped 20-30%. Now we need days to add new unit tests... No one knows how to fix the issue?